# 2 tkinter files cannot communicate with each other

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm very new Python coding and I'm having trouble linking my tkinter files, currently have 2 files 1 is the welcomescreen.py where user selects the form they wish to fill out, now I want user to go to the form they have selected do the activity and comebck to welcome, like press the quit button.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import messagebox


class Feedback:
    def __init__(self, master):

#CODING
#at the end

def main():
root = Tk()
feedback = Feedback(root)
root.mainloop()

if __name__ == "__main__":main()
```

and second file is something like this, actually i coded it pretty much in the same manner

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import messagebox

class Proj_pres:
    """Defininf clickable labels in frame"""
# CODES
# CODES

# at the end


def main():
    root = Tk()
    proj_pres = Proj_pres(root)
    root.mainloop()


if __name__ == '__main__':main()
```

I tried the `exec` command but it didn't help.

Comment: It's very unclear how the snippets you've provided relates to the issue you're having, which is unclear too.

Comment: How is the title of the question related to the issue you're having?

Comment: Here i have edited the title.. hopefully now it makes more sense :), but u know how it is for new programmers we get frustrated easily as things seem very straightforward but on script execution either throws an error or does nothing...

Comment: maybe first create working program in one file and later you can try to split it int many files. Currently

Comment: to make code more readalbe don't put `main()` in the same line as `if` (or `else`). Read [PEP 8 -- Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)

Answer (score 1):

Seems like all you need to do is `import` one of the script files you have in by the other one. Let's say you have the script file `my_module1.py` which has the widget class `MyWidget1` and `my_module2.py` that has `MyWidget2`. Also the *`main`* part of your body should look like the following:

```
import my_module2
import tkinter as tk

...

if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = tk.Tk()
    welcome = MyWidget1(...)
    welcome.quit_button['command'] = welcome.destroy
    form = my_module2.MyWidget2(...)
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Hi thanks for that, but it didn't work as it throw into whirl pool of error on my page 2 where as if i run my page you standalone it works fine

Comment: This isn't an exact solution. You need to adapt it a bit. How does your main look like?